How to test cmdline arguments (argv) on a TUI application running on a pyte terminal in a child process
I have a curses-based TUI application that I start up like this:
def parse_arguments():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Command Line Arguments',
                                   formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', type=str, help='Config file path', default=None)
  return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # === Command line arguments ===
  args = parse_arguments()
  if args.config:
      CONFIG_PATH = args.config

  def init_path(stdscr: curses.window) -> Paths:
      global interrupted
      # initialize some things here
      if initui.interrupted:
          interrupted = True
  try:
      curses.wrapper(init_path)
      if not interrupted:
          curses.wrapper(main, logger=app_logger)
            
 
 def main(stdscr: curses.window, logger: Optional[logging.Logger] = None):
    # more setup and initialization
    if logger:
        logger.info("Starting up the application")
    ui.ui_loop()

I am able to test the user interface using pyte, with some code I referenced from https://mrossinek.gitlab.io/programming/testing-tui-applications-in-python/:
def run_tui_test(screen_file_path, keystrokes, W=80, H=24):
    # Child process initializes the TUI while parent process sets up virtual screen
    pid, f_d = os.forkpty()
    if pid == 0:
        interrupted = False

        def init_path(stdscr: curses.window):
            global interrupted
            # initialize some things here
            if initui.interrupted:
                interrupted = True

        curses.wrapper(init_path)
        if not interrupted:
            curses.wrapper(main, logger=None)
    else:
        screen = pyte.Screen(W, H)
        stream = pyte.ByteStream(screen)

        # Send keystrokes to TUI
        for keystroke in keystrokes:
            # print(f"Sending key: {repr(keystroke)} | Encoded: {keystroke.encode()}")
            os.write(f_d, keystroke.encode())

        # Scrape pseudo-terminal's screen
        while True:
            try:
                [f_d], _, _ = select.select([f_d], [], [], 1)
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, ValueError):
                break
            else:
                try:
                    # Scrape screen of child process
                    data = os.read(f_d, 1024)
                    stream.feed(data)
                except OSError:
                    break

        # Read expected lines from file
        with open(screen_file_path, 'r') as file:
            expected_lines = file.read().split('\n')

        # Compare expected lines with screen.display
        for i, (expected_line, screen_line) in enumerate(zip(expected_lines, screen.display)):
            screen_line_str = ''.join(screen_line)
            assert expected_line == screen_line_str, f"Line {i+1} does not match: expected '{expected_line}', got '{screen_line_str}'"

This all works well but... is there a way that I could pass arguments (such as --config) when testing the TUI?
